# How to get a value from a Array symfony2.8

Tags: php, symfony

Hi everyone i'm looking for a way to get a value in a variable but i'm stuck with an array like

```
$prixArrayArticle = $article->getArticlePlateforme()->getValues();
dump($prixArrayArticle);
```

gives me

```
ReassortController.php on line 1149:
array:1 [▼
0 => ArticlePlateforme {#1469 ▼
-article: Article {#1321 ▶}
-plateforme: Plateforme {#1051 ▶}
-codeProduitGv: "365717          "
-fournisseurCommun: FournisseurAchatsAdherents {#1445 ▶}
-referenceFournisseur: "100050           "
-minimumCommande: 1
-colisage: 12
-qtePalette: 12
-decolisable: true
-stock: 182
-dateCreation: DateTime {#1326 ▶}
-present: true
-articleSubstitution: null
-prix: PersistentCollection {#1430 ▼
  -snapshot: array:1 [ …1]
  -owner: ArticlePlateforme {#1469}
  -association: array:19 [ …19]
  -em: EntityManager {#137 …11}
  -backRefFieldName: null
  -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#1261 …}
  -isDirty: false
  #collection: ArrayCollection {#1439 ▼
    -elements: array:1 [▼
      0 => Prix {#1412 ▼
        -id: 4175988
        -dateDebut: DateTime {#1325 ▶}
        -dateFin: DateTime {#1324 ▶}
        -prixNet: "4.970"
        -prixVenteConseille: null
        -quantiteMinimum: null
        -type: "permanent"
        -numeroPromo: null
        -offreComplementaire: false
        -minimumCommande: 0
        -colisage: 0
        -invisible: null
        -present: true
      }
    ]
  }
  #initialized: true
}
-prixPromo: PersistentCollection {#1399 ▶}
}
]
```

and this

```
$article = $requeteArticle->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
```

give me this

```
ReassortController.php on line 1129:
Article {#769 ▼
-id: 1000940
-nom: "FILM DE PAILLAGE FRAISES FRESAFILM 1M40X10M"
-nomCourt: "FILM PAILLAGE FRAISES 1M40X10M"
-gamme: 5
-ecoContribution: "0.00"
-ecoMobilier: "0.00"
-quantiteAchat: "1.00"
-nombreUvParUa: "1.00"
-prixVenteConseille: "9.50"
-present: true
-tauxTva: TauxTva {#908 ▶}
-marque: null
-articleGencod: PersistentCollection {#1007 ▶}
-sousFamille: SousFamille {#635 ▶}
-articlePlateforme: PersistentCollection {#960 ▶}
-uniteAchat: UniteConditionnement {#833 ▶}
-uniteVente: UniteConditionnement {#833 ▶}
}
```

how can i get the name value for example in a variable because the array only have one index and i really don't know how to get a value with this array

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the properties are protected and that you have getters for them in your ArticlePlateforme and Article class, you should be able to get them like that:

```
$articleName = $prixArrayArticle[0]->getArticle()->getNom();
```

Otherwise, if the properties are public, you could simply get them like:

```
$articleName = $prixArrayArticle[0]->article->nom;
```

Comment: This is ok for the name(i've found it 10 mins ago) but for -prixNet: i don't find the way to

Comment: I believe 
$prices = $prixArrayArticle[0]->getPrix()->toArray(); 
should give you an array like array("0" => array("prixNet" => "4.970", ... ))